# Cakephp and charts

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have located a chart making program and would like to integrate it into my cakephp 2.0 application. The program is xml/swf charts found at http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/ . Is there anyone that is familiar with this program that can help integrate this into cakephp?  I have tried a few things but nothing has worked so far. Or do you know of another program that would give us the same look and feel, and is just as easy to work with.

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: Ok, I have this figured out but now I need to take database data and format it a specific way into an xml file. Wondering if there is anything out there right now that I can read that would help me do this.  The data is already in the database I just need to take some of it and create an xml file. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The one i have used is this http://www.highcharts.com/ that uses jquery instead of flash easy to install and to use with similar results...

With yours you need to create a action/view that gives you this data. In the action you should use something `like $this->layout = false;` or `$this->layout = xml;` Then if you choose the second one you would need to put in the view the xml headers you want to use

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

then in the view you write the xml code.To do the xml parsing you may use [the cakephp library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html). If you choose the first one just put it in the view and instead of $content_for_layout put the xml data...

Hope this helps you :D